# Joining and Splitting an element from an array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

So I am learning JavaScript slowly but surely, can someone help me figure out the most efficient way of using `join()`and `split()` for very large array or arrays? Im talking thousands or lines from a spreadsheet... This is what I have so far.

```js
function joinsplitPaste () {
    var data = [["mike",33,,"KS","male"],["jan",32," ","KS","female"],["dave",33,,"KS","male"],["mike",33, ,"KS","male"],["stan",31,,"KS","male"],["beth",19,"dataText","KS","female"]];
    var dataJoin = [];
    //sample is made up
    for (i = 0;i<data.length;i++) {
        return data[i].join(" ");  
        dataJoin.push(data[i]) ;
    }

    var dataSplit = [];
    /* output - [["mike 33  "KS" "male"],["jan" 32 " " "KS" "female"],["dave" 33  "KS" "male"], and so on...*/                          
    for (i = 0;i<data.length;i++) {
        return dataJoin[i].Split(" ");  
        dataSplit.push(dataJoin[i]);
    }
    //hopefully  dataSplit == data?
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve instead of what you want?

Comment: Show us your instead output.

Comment: why do you have return inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

based on the last comment in your sample code, I am assuming the endgoal you are after is that 'dataSplit' array should be equal to original 'data' array.

However, there are 2 problems with the sample code due to which you can not achieve what you wish:

1. presence of 'return' statement inside 'for' loop: which stops execution of first loop just after first iteration and prevents second loop from even getting started.
2. equality check doesn't work for non-primitive data types: array and object data types in javascript are non-primitive and equality check never works for them unless the two operands are really pointing to the same location in memory.

E.g.: {} == {} // false (both objects, however identical, point to 2 different memory locations so they are never 'equal')

Similarly, [1,2,3] == [1,2,3] // false (for the reason same as described for objects)

Coming to the sample code, I have a revised version for you to generate 'dataSplit' array *identical* to original 'data' array but never equal since they are two different variables, hence, different memory locations. The use of join and split, however, is correct. Revised sample:

```
function joinsplitPaste(){
  var data = [["mike",33,,"KS","male"],["jan",32," ","KS","female"],["dave",33,,"KS","male"],["mike",33, ,"KS","male"],["stan",31,,"KS","male"],["beth",19,"dataText","KS","female"]];
  var dataJoin = [];
  for (i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
    dataJoin.push(data[i].join(" ")) ;
  }
  var dataSplit = [];
  for (i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
    dataSplit.push(dataJoin[i].split(" ")) ;
  }
}
```